# Updating physics engine ina separate thread, is this wise?

Tags: multithreading, silverlight, xna

I'm 100% new to threading, as a start I've decided I want to muck around with using it to update my physics in a separate thread. I'm using a third party physics engine called Farseer, here's what I'm doing:

```
// class level declarations
System.Threading.Thread thread;
Stopwatch threadUpdate = new Stopwatch();

//In the constructor:
PhysicsEngine()
{
(...)

            thread = new System.Threading.Thread(
                        new System.Threading.ThreadStart(PhysicsThread));
            threadUpdate.Start();

            thread.Start();
}


        public void PhysicsThread()
        {
            int milliseconds = TimeSpan.FromTicks(111111).Milliseconds;
            while(true)
            {
                if (threadUpdate.Elapsed.Milliseconds > milliseconds)
                {
                    world.Step(threadUpdate.Elapsed.Milliseconds / 1000.0f);
                    threadUpdate.Stop();
                    threadUpdate.Reset();
                    threadUpdate.Start();
                }
            }
        }
```

Is this an ok way to update physics or should there be some stuff I should look out for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a game you need to synchronise your physics update to the game's frame rate. This is because your rendering and gameplay will depend on the output of your physics engine each frame. And your physics engine will depend on user input and gameplay events each frame.

This means that the only advantage of calculating your physics on a separate thread is that it can run on a separate CPU core to the rest of your game logic and rendering. (Pretty safe for PC these days, and the mobile space is just starting to get dual-core.)

This allows them to both physics and gameplay/rendering run concurrently - but the drawback is that you need to have some mechanism to prevent one thread from modifying data while the other thread is using that data. This is generally quite difficult to implement.

Of course, if your physics *isn't* dependent on user input - like Angry Birds or The Incredible Machine (ie: the user presses "play" and the simulation runs) - in that case it's possible for you to calculate your physics simulation in advance, recording its output for playback. But instead of blocking the main thread you could move this time-consuming operation to a background thread - which is a well understood problem. You could even go so far as to start playing your recording back in the main thread, even before it is finished recording!

Comment: Yep, most of my problems are basically caused by my game logic calling physics operations (such as raycasts) or my physics engine sending collision callbacks out to the rest of the engine. However I don't want to implement a solution which will only work on a specific kind of game since I'm trying to build a game engine which can handle various kinds of games.. The problem is creating a solution for the physics problems seems to require that I re-write parts of the engine such that it becomes less clear and straight forward. I guess clarity is a sacrifice that hsa to be made for performance.

Answer (score 1):

there is nothing wrong with your approach in general. Moving time-consuming operations, such as physics engine calculations to a separate thread is often a good idea. However, I am assuming that your application includes some sort of visual representation of your physics objects in the UI? If this is the case you are going to run into problems.

The UI controls in Silverlight have thread affinity, i.e. you cannot update their state from within the thread you have created in the above example. In order to update their state you are going to have to invoke via the Dispatcher, e.g. TextBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(...).

Another alternative is to use a Silverlight [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28VS.95%29.aspx). This is a useful little class that allows you to do time-consuming work. It will move your work onto a background thread, avoiding the need to create your own `System.Threading.Thread`. It will also provide events that marshal results back onto the UI thread for you.

Much simpler!

Comment: I'm actually doing this in XNA as well (it's an XNA/silverlight game). Any idea how any of your advice might apply to XNA?

Comment: Are you creating a WP7 game? If so, take a look at the many articles on the web, e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows-phone-7/BounceBall.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately that article doesn't seem to cover threading which is where I'm having my problems. I really need to use threading because the performance boost it gives me is absolutely massive and can often mean the difference between a stuttering game and silky smooth framerate. The game I'm working on right now has its main bottleneck in the physics engine and that's where I need to focus on optimizing...